# Error No such file while saving the json file in s3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Code is below

Below is code.py

```
import os
import csv
import json
import boto3


def read_s3(bucket, key):

    try:
        s3_read = boto3.client('s3')
        obj = s3_read.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        data = obj['Body'].read()
        contents = data.decode('utf-8')
        data_list = []
        csv_file = csv.DictReader(contents)
        data_list = list(csv_file)

        with open(bucket + key + 'test.json', 'w+') as output:
          json.dump(data_list, output)
          print (output)
        return output
    except Exception as err:
        logger.error("Error in read_s3  " + str(err))
```

Below is the lambda handler

```
import json
import code

def lambda_handler(event, context):
     json_response = code.read_s3('bucketname', 'path')
     return {
      'statusCode': 200,
      'body': json.dumps(json_response )
     }
```

I ma getting the error "../../test.csvtest.json'"  No such file or directory:

- I have test.csv in the s3bucket/folder1/folder2/test.csv
- I am converting to json and `return the json response`

Disclaimer I don't want to use PANDAS since i don't want to use layer

Comment: Where is that error occurring? Please provide the entire error output.

Comment: @AMC with open(bucket + key + 'test.json', 'w+') as output: where the error occurs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is working example :

code.py

```py
import os
import csv
import json
import boto3


def read_s3(bucket, key):

    try:
        s3_read = boto3.client('s3')
        obj = s3_read.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        # for python 3 you need to decode the incoming bytes:
        lines = obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split()
        data_list = []
        # now iterate over those lines
        csv_file = csv.DictReader(lines)
        data_list = list(csv_file)
            
        #print(data_list)
        return data_list
    except Exception as err:
        print("Error in read_s3  " + str(err))
```

lambda_function.py

```py
import json
import code

def lambda_handler(event, context):
     json_response = code.read_s3('fileuploadprocess', 'lambdapackage/addresses.csv')
     return {
      'statusCode': 200,
      'body': json.dumps(json_response )
     }
```

Two things are doing wrong:

- when you pushing csv data into dictionary not required to push it again into json file
- in lambda folder as `/tmp/sample.json` if you want directory structure you need to create directory. So your `bucket/key/sample.json` will not work because this directory will not existing in your lambda package.
- if you use `json.dump(data_list, output)` then this return file object which you can't dump in response because only accept string or json. Either you have to read this json file again and return data.

This code tested and working fine.